# Swap references of 3 hexagon neighbors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a two dimensional array that stores all hexagons. It's an array of `Hexagon` objects that is indexed with 2 integers.

I want to swap 3 hexagons with each other like i showed in the picture.

Can anyone help me with the algorithm that should do the job?

Thanks!

[image: Example]

Here is the functions for creating hexagons.

```
    public void CreateGrid(int gridWidth, int gridHeight)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < gridHeight; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; x++)
            {


          GameObject Hexagon = Instantiate(HexagonPre, 
                                           Vector2.zero, 
                                           Quaternion.identity, 
                                           HexGrid);

                Vector2 gridPos = new Vector2(x, y);
                Hexagon.transform.position = CalcWorldPos(gridPos);
                Hexagon.transform.name = "X: " + x + " | Y: " + y;
            }
       }
}

 Vector2 CalcWorldPos(Vector2 gridPos)
{
    float offset = 0;
    if(gridPos.y %2 != 0)
        offset = hexWidth / 2f;

    float x = startPos.x + gridPos.x * hexWidth + offset;
    float y = startPos.y - gridPos.y * hexHeight * 0.75f;

    return new Vector2(x, y);

}
```

Okay I shared how the game looks like. I click somewhere in the game. The game finds 3 closest hexagons on where i click. Then I change the locations of those 3 hexagons. (I already did that). But somehow i need my array to know that those 3 hexagons swapped with each other. Be careful this would be any 3 hexagons. So we need an algorithm for this to work for any 3 hexagons to swap their place in the array.

Video showing what I already have: youtube.com/watch?v=fVvQd47OswQ&feature=youtu.be

Comment: what's the input of this algorithm? Is it an unordered list of 3 hexagons (and their coordinates)?

Comment: You are lacking enough information in this question. Please provide some more information on how you are interacting with these objects, if you have any scripts, or if you have any code already.

Comment: @ErikOverflow Sorry about that, I thought this information would be enough. I edited the question and added some functions.

Comment: @Ruzihm I edited and added more information.

Comment: Let me be a little more specific. I will click somewhere on the screen and the game selects 3 closest hexagons like this. It should switch places with each other like i shown in the picture. The problem is we should know what is the x,y position of the closest hexagon's x,y coordinates for the right one.

Comment: @Ruzihm Yeah i have grid coordinates of any adjacent 3 hexagons that i choose. But the problem is I do not know how to change those 3's place with each other. It is not simple as for example Hex[x,y] = Hex[x+1,y+1] because it is not always the case. There is a difference in calculations between odd rows and even rows( I guess). So i just need an algorithm to actually get those 3 locations swapped. I have world space coordinates as well. But it does not matter for me. All i need is to change their space with each other in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the coordinates of the 3 hexagons, then you can determine which hexagon has the unique Y coordinate, and determine which of the other two is on the right and which is on the left:

```
Vector2Int hexagonACoord;
Vector2Int hexagonBCoord;
Vector2Int hexagonCCoord;

Vector2Int loneHexagonCoord;
Vector2Int leftHexagonCoord;
Vector2Int rightHexagonCoord;

if (hexagonACoord.y != hexagonBCoord.y  && hexagonACoord.y != hexagonCCoord.y)
{
    loneHexagonCoord = hexagonACoord;

    leftHexagonCoord = hexagonBCoord;
    rightHexagonCoord = hexagonCCoord;
}
else if (hexagonBCoord.y != hexagonCCoord.y  && hexagonBCoord.y != hexagonACoord.y)
{
    loneHexagonCoord = hexagonBCoord;

    leftHexagonCoord = hexagonACoord;
    rightHexagonCoord = hexagonCCoord;
}
else 
{
    loneHexagonCoord = hexagonCCoord;

    leftHexagonCoord = hexagonACoord;
    rightHexagonCoord = hexagonBCoord;
}

if (leftHexagonCoord.x > rightHexagonCoord.x) 
{
    Vector2Int tempCoord = leftHexagonCoord;
    leftHexagonCoord = rightHexagonCoord;
    rightHexagonCoord = tempCoord;
}
```

Then depending on if the lone hex is on top, we can determine which direction to rotate in order to rotation clockwise:

```
if (loneHexagonCoord.y > leftHexagonCoord.y)
{
    Hexagon tempHex = hexagonsArray[loneHexagonCoord.x, loneHexagonCoord.y];
    hexagonsArray[loneHexagonCoord.x, loneHexagonCoord.y] = 
            hexagonsArray[rightHexagonCoord.x, rightHexagonCoord.y];
    hexagonsArray[rightHexagonCoord.x, rightHexagonCoord.y] =  
            hexagonsArray[leftHexagonCoord.x, leftHexagonCoord.y];
    hexagonsArray[leftHexagonCoord.x, leftHexagonCoord.y] = tempHex;
}
else 
{
    Hexagon tempHex = hexagonsArray[loneHexagonCoord.x, loneHexagonCoord.y];
    hexagonsArray[loneHexagonCoord.x, loneHexagonCoord.y] =  
            hexagonsArray[leftHexagonCoord.x, leftHexagonCoord.y];
    hexagonsArray[leftHexagonCoord.x, leftHexagonCoord.y] =  
            hexagonsArray[rightHexagonCoord.x, rightHexagonCoord.y];
    hexagonsArray[rightHexagonCoord.x, rightHexagonCoord.y] = tempHex;
}
```

Then, update their `HexCoordinates` components on where they are:

```
hexagonsArray[loneHexagonCoord.x, loneHexagonCoord.y]
            .GetComponent<HexCoordinates>().Coordinates = new Vector2Int(
                loneHexagonCoord.x, loneHexagonCoord.y);

hexagonsArray[leftHexagonCoord.x, leftHexagonCoord.y]
            .GetComponent<HexCoordinates>().Coordinates = new Vector2Int(
                leftHexagonCoord.x, leftHexagonCoord.y);

hexagonsArray[rightHexagonCoord.x, rightHexagonCoord.y]
            .GetComponent<HexCoordinates>().Coordinates = new Vector2Int(
                rightHexagonCoord.x, rightHexagonCoord.y);
```

---

When I answered below, there was no indication that logic to select the 3 hexagons was already complete. I'm going to leave this up because it answers a very related question:

---

Well, we can divide the intersections of the hex grid into triangles, and pair them into parallelograms like so:

[image]

The Y coordinate of the parallelogram that a mouse position (in world space) is in is simply:

```
float pgYCoord = Mathf.Floor((startPos.y - mousePos.y) / (hexHeight * 0.75f));
```

The X coordinate of the parallelogram that a mouse position is in is more complicated:

```
float xOffsetAtMouseY =  startPos.x + hexWidth / 2f * (startPos.y - mousePos.y) / (hexHeight * 0.75f)
float pgXCoord = Mathf.Floor((mousePos.x - xOffsetAtMouseY) / hexWidth);
```

And then determine if the mouse in the A or the B triangle of that parallelogram:

```
float vertDistFromTopEdge = Mathf.Repeat(startPos.y-mousePos.y, hexHeight * 0.75f );
float horizDistFromTopLeftCorner = mousePos.x - startPos.x - pgXCoord*hexWidth - pgYCoord * hexWidth / 2f;

bool isInATriangle = 
        vertDistFromTopEdge 
        < 1.5f * hexHeight 
          - horizDistFromTopLeftCorner * (hexHeight * 0.75) / (hexWidth / 2f);
```

Then depending on if we're in an A triangle or not, we can determine the coordinates of the hexagons in clockwise order:

```
Vector2Int hexagonCoordA;
Vector2Int hexagonCoordB;
Vector2Int hexagonCoordC;

if (isInATriangle)
{
    hexagonCoordA = new Vector2Int(pgXCoord, pgYCoord);
    hexagonCoordB = new Vector2Int(pgXCoord+1, pgYCoord);
    hexagonCoordC = new Vector2Int(pgXCoord, pgYCoord+1);
} 
else 
{
    hexagonCoordA = new Vector2Int(pgXCoord, pgYCoord+1);
    hexagonCoordB = new Vector2Int(pgXCoord+1, pgYCoord);
    hexagonCoordC = new Vector2Int(pgXCoord+1, pgYCoord+1);
}

// every 2 rows, the pg x coord grows 1 additional higher than the hex x coord

hexagonCoordA.x += Mathf.Floor(0.5f*hexagonCoordA.y);
hexagonCoordB.x += Mathf.Floor(0.5f*hexagonCoordB.y);
hexagonCoordC.x += Mathf.Floor(0.5f*hexagonCoordC.y)
```

If any of the hexagonCoord variables have invalid indices (more appropriate in a separate question), then the mouse is not currently over an intersection of 3 hexagons. Otherwise, you can then swap the 3 hexagons.

```
int arrayXSize = hexagonArray.GetLength(0);
int arrayYSize = hexagonArray.GetLength(1);

if (   hexagonCoordA.x >= 0 && hexagonCoordA.x < arrayXSize 
    && hexagonCoordA.y >= 0 && hexagonCoordA.y < arrayYSize
    && hexagonCoordB.x >= 0 && hexagonCoordB.x < arrayXSize 
    && hexagonCoordB.y >= 0 && hexagonCoordB.y < arrayYSize
    && hexagonCoordC.x >= 0 && hexagonCoordC.x < arrayXSize 
    && hexagonCoordC.y >= 0 && hexagonCoordC.y < arrayYSize)
{

    Hexagon tempHex = hexagonsArray[hexagonCoordA.x, hexagonCoordA.y];
    hexagonsArray[hexagonCoordA.x, hexagonCoordA.y] =  
            hexagonsArray[hexagonCoordC.x, hexagonCoordC.y];
    hexagonsArray[hexagonCoordC.x, hexagonCoordC.y] =  
            hexagonsArray[hexagonCoordB.x, hexagonCoordB.y];
    hexagonsArray[hexagonCoordB.x, hexagonCoordB.y] = tempHex;


    Vector3 temp = hexagonA.transform.position;
    hexagonA.transform.position = hexagonB.transform.position;
    hexagonB.transform.position = hexagonC.transform.position;
    hexagonC.transform.position = temp;

}
```

Comment: Okay, I'm trying to understand it now. Once i'm done i'll let you know. You're awesome thank you!

Comment: I can already flip it. But the array has no idea that i do that. Somehow i need to tell the array that i flip it and update the array with the right positions.

Comment: I think you are creating a problem that you don't really need. Create a class to represent a `Hexagon`, that will contain two attributes: `worldPosition` and and `gridPosition`. Create a `Hexagon[,] matrix` and when you click a hexagon, you will just have to figure out which hexagons will rotate and use the attributes to help you.

Comment: I still do not see how that will solve my problem. Thank you for your help tho. I guess i'm not capable of understanding this

Comment: I'll read these answers over and over again. I hope i will get it. Thank you all for the help!

Comment: @FaTaLL I read some more comments and realized that you don't actually need an answer to rotate the positions of the hexagons, but the references in your hexagon array.  I have now edited the top part of my answer to address that...

Comment: @Ruzihm Oh PERFECT!! This is exactly what i needed. You are awesome!! Sorry for my stupidty. Could not explain myself clearly.

Comment: @Ruzihm I implemented it and WORKED like a boss. I'm glad you helped me. Thumps up! :)

Comment: @FaTaLL Edited my answer to update the hex's `HexCoordinate` components. This should fix the bug in the other question.

Comment: @Ruzihm I found the bug and edited the answer. After we find the lone hexagon, there was no guarantee to know the right and left hexagons. I added some if statements and checked last 2 hexagon's x positions and set them correctly.

Comment: oh I used `rightHexagonCoord = leftHexagonCoord;` instead of `rightHexagonCoord = tempCoord;` let me fix that.

Comment: Whoops i did not even see that code. Well I'm removing my solution, yours is much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job

```
void Rotate3Hexagons(GameObject hexagon1, GameObject hexagon2, GameObject hexagon3){
    Vector3 firstPos = hexagon1.transform.position;
    hexagon1.transform.position = hexagon2.transform.position;
    hexagon2.transform.position = hexagon3.transform.position;
    hexagon3.transform.position = firstPos;
}
```

In order to convert from world coordinates to grid coordinates, you need to set an inverse function for your `CalcWorldPos` function.

```
Vector2 CalcGridPos(Vector2 worldPos)
{
    float offset = 0;
    //the first thing to do is to decide if offset is 0 or hexWidth/2
    //I guess you can figure it out    
    Vector2 gridPos = new Vector2();
    gridPos.x = (worldPos.x - startPos.x - offset) / hexWidth;
    gridPos.y = (-worldPos.y + startPos.y) / hexHeight * 0.75f;

    return gridPos;
}
```

Comment: I want to swap their space in two dimensional array. I wish that would be this easy ^^

Comment: From what I understood, you convert from grid coordinates to world coordinates, if you want your grid coordinates after this rotation, you just need an inverse function that turns world coordinates into grid coordinates.

Comment: For example, I choose 3 hexagons in the game. Lets say their space in the array are (1,0), (2,0),(1,1) (like i showed in the picture above.). I know their space in the array.

Comment: I'll modify my answer.

Comment: Okay  I shared how the game looks like. I click somewhere in the game. The game finds 3 closest hexagons on where i click. Then I change the locations of those 3 hexagons. (I already did that). But somehow i need my array to know that those 3 hexagons swapped with each other. Be careful this would be any 3 hexagons. So we need an algorithm for this to work for any 3 hexagons to swap their place in the array. I hope it is clear now ^^

Comment: I need this for colors. If 3 colors are the same of any 3 neighbors hexagons, i should destroy them.

Comment: @Ruzihm Oh wait I'm gonna take a video. Your answer might be what i'm looking for tho.

Comment: Modified. You can create a class for your hexagon as well, that stores both the grid position and the world position, then you would have a simple bidimensional array of this class. This way, you would have reference to the positions you want to swap.

Comment: Also to clarify your comment, it can't be "any 3 hexagons", they're always going to be 3 hexagons that share a vertex right?

Comment: @Ruzihm Exactly

Comment: @Daniel I shared a video below Ruzihm's answer. I think that will tell the problem a little bit better. i'm checking the answers

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to swap the positions between them its easy:

```
Vector3 tmpPos = hexagon1.transform.position; 
hexagon1.transform.position = hexagon2.transform.position;
hexagon2.transform.position = hexagon3.transform.position;
hexagon3.transform.position = tmpPos;
```

Comment: Simple, but solves the problem. I like this. Good job!

Comment: I need the algorithm for this. There will be a lot of swapping. Thanks tho :)